# Which is the right usage in Protractor test? await expect(someFn()).toBe.. or expect(await someFn()).toBe

Tags: angular, async-await, jasmine, protractor

For e2e testing, I use Protractor with Jasmine and Control Flow is disabled. I am aware that Protractor uses [jasminewd2](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd) an adapter for Jasmine. And that it enhances expect so that it automatically unwraps promises before performing the assertion. So both the statements below has the same effect.

```
expect(await someFn()).toBe..
await expect(someFn()).toBe..
```

Is there any situation where above statements will behave differently? What is the recommended option? Example spec [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.4.1/spec/ts/basic/element_spec.ts) follows the second approach of putting await first. Is there any advantage in doing this?

[Edit 1]
One difference I found is the way in which Promise reject is handled. Try catch will work in both cases, but second option allows catch-ing Promise way.

```
it('should throw error 1', async () => {
  try {
    expect(await someFn()).toBe(1);
  } catch (err) {
    expect(err).toEqual('Unable to calculate');
  }
});

it('should throw error 2', async () => {
  await expect(someFn()).toBe(1)
                        .catch((err) => expect(err).toEqual('Unable to calculate'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right with your explanations about jasminewd2.

I would go with option 1, putting the `await` inside the `expect()` function, because there lies the actual Promise to be awaited.

I don't see any advantage for the wrappers, now that the control flow in Protractor has been replaced by async/await.

Comment: One difference I see is the way Promise reject is handled.